# Postfix. Отправляю письмо, а она падает в СПАМ

Tags: postfix

Ситуация следующая: если я отправляю письма со своего сервера, например, на yandex, то они доходят без проблем, а если я с yandex отправляю, то на почте яндекса приходит письмо о том, что оно спам и не будет доставлено. Вот что пишут логи:

````
Aug  1 15:50:15 brusnika postfix/smtpd[23142]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from forward201c.mail.yandex.net[178.154.239.220]: 554 5.7.1 Service unavailable; Client host [178.154.239.220] blocked using bl.spamcom.net; from=<test.brusnika@yandex.ru> to=<test@brusnika.fun> proto=ESMTP helo=<forward201c.mail.yandex.net>
Aug  1 15:50:15 brusnika postfix/smtpd[23142]: disconnect from forward201c.mail.yandex.net[178.154.239.220] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=0/1 data=0/1 rset=1 quit=1 commands=6/8```
````

Так же настройки /etc/postfix/main.cf следующие:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
compatibility_level = 2

smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/mail/public.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/mail/private.key
smtpd_tls_security_level=may
smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level=may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

#smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = brusnika.fun
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = localhost.$mydomain, localhost, localhost.localdomain
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all

virtual_mailbox_base = /home/mail
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_alias_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_minimum_uid = 1024
virtual_uid_maps = static:1024
virtual_gid_maps = static:1024
virtual_transport = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1

smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_exceptions_networks = $mynetworks
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth

smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes

content_filter = scan:[127.0.0.1]:10024

smtpd_client_restrictions = 
 permit_mynetworks
 permit_sasl_authenticated
 reject_unauth_pipelining
 permit

smtpd_helo_restrictions =
 permit

smtpd_sender_restrictions =
 permit_mynetworks
 permit_sasl_authenticated
 reject_non_fqdn_sender
 reject_unknown_sender_domain
 check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access
 permit

smtpd_relay_restrictions = 
 permit_mynetworks
 permit_sasl_authenticated
 defer_unauth_destination

policy-spf_time_limit = 3600s

smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
 permit_mynetworks
 permit_sasl_authenticated
 reject_non_fqdn_recipient
 reject_unauth_destination
 reject_unknown_recipient_domain
 reject_unverified_recipient
 reject_unknown_client_hostname
 reject_invalid_helo_hostname
 reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname
 reject_unknown_helo_hostname
 reject_rbl_client bl.spamcom.net
 reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org
 reject_rbl_client dul.ru
 reject_rbl_client dnsbl.abuse.ch
 check_policy_service unix:private/policy-spf
 permit

smtpd_data_restrictions = 
 permit

smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions =
 permit
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, в чем проблема.

Comment: `Client host [178.154.239.220] blocked using bl.spamcom.net`. нужен перевод?

Comment: Нет, это мне понятно, но почему блок происходит?

Comment: https://www.spamcop.net/anonsignup.shtml

Comment: ну и даже если отправитель будет чист аки стёклышко, письмо-то доставлять просто некуда: нет mx записи у вашего домена.

Comment: Так, я понял. Спасибо.